# Include describe block inside describe block, mocha

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, puppeteer

I am trying to include a describe block inside a describe test suite like so:

```
test = () => {
  describe('test', () => {
    it('test', () => {})
});


describe('general test', () => {
   it('some test', () => {})
   it('some test', () => {})
   describe('sometest',() => {
      test(); 
   })
   it('continue general test', () => {});
})
```

Comment: So what is your issue or problem you are facing?

Comment: is there a reason why you're trying to use a function instead of directly writing it inside the the describe block?

Comment: Yes, I repeat the same test in different scenarios, and I dont want to duplicate code,

Comment: The second describe block runs asynchronously and the first describe block keeps running.